# What is this file: wp-config-wpe.php?

Tags: wp-config

I just have been given access to an unmaintained Wordpress site. I have access to the Wordpress admin site, and also to the filesystem tree and PhpMyAdmin site through the host admin site.

I'm trying to setup a developer environment for this site. What I found is that there is no `wp-config.php` file, but there is a `wp-config-wpe.php` instead.

How is it even possible that the site is running in production? Where in the Wordpress tree is configured the path to that config file?

Comment: If there is a line in `.htaccess` that redirects to this file, WP will be unaware of the change. The WPE suffix usually points to hosting by WP Engine.

Comment: The `.htaccess` file doesn't mention the config file

Comment: And is the site hosted at WP Engine?

Comment: It is hosted on GoDaddy, and I know it has been migrated from Linode a few months ago. I don't know about further history.

Comment: Given that the site has been unmaintained and moved around there could be malware involved. That requires specialized attention. Or move the content to a fresh install.

Comment: Line 34 - 42 of wp-load.php is where the require call to wp-config.php is made from. Have you checked in there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wp-config.php` file do not have to be at the root directory, it can also be at the directory above it (that way they are not easily accessible from the web even if php interpreter malfunctions).

Comment: Indeed, the wp-config.php file is located one level above the root directory